# How to make VS Code read Python imports without displaying yellow squigglies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've fiddled with a problem, and have not been able to find a solution. VS Code will not recognize module imports, and thus put a yellow squiggly line under the functions, like this:

[image: squigglies] [image]

These are on every function that imports, but it renders and executes perfectly fine when the main file is executed. *The issue is solely in the visualization of the code within VS Code.*

## My Versions

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.5
- VS Code 1.36.1
- Python 3.7.3

## I've Tried

- Setting VS Code source to `/usr/bin/python`
- Setting VS Code source to `/usr/local/bin/python3`
- Reinstalling Python
- Reinstalling Python3
- Googling
- Changing `false` to `true` in `"python.jediEnabled":` in `settings.json`

## My Structure:

To illustrate the problem, here is a simple app:

**Directory**

[image: folder structure]

Note: Same error with **init**.py in the animals/ directory.

#### init.py

```py
from animals.bird import *
from animals.reptile import *
```

#### app.py

```py
from __init__ import *
print_bird()
print_reptile()
```

#### animals/reptile.py

```py
def print_reptile():
    print("I'm a reptile. ssssssssss!")
```

#### animals/bird.py

```py
def print_bird():
    print("I'm a bird. tweet!")
```

---

And when running `python3 app.py` or `python app.py` the result is always the expected text of:

```
I'm a bird. tweet!
I'm a reptile. ssssssssss!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things, you don't need `from __init__` to import, you can just use `from animals import bird, reptile` once you have the `__init__.py` file set up.

Then I'm assuming you have the vs code python extension installed. In which case, in your project root set a .env file containing the python project root (not necessarily the same thing). Eg. my python code is under src in the project root, so I have in my env file:

```
PYTHONPATH="./src/project/"
```

Then in your settings you can set :

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}\\<project>.env",
```

That should tell vs code where your "python root" is, so all your paths will be correct.

Drove me nuts that until I got this sorted :)

Comment: Oh wow, never heard of an .env file or `python.envFile` in settings.json. I'm having trouble Googling with .env files. Should the the PYTHONPATH go to the directory that contains the main .py file, or should it reference the .py itself? _(e.g., `./src/` vs `./src/app.py`)_

What is the `<project>.env` referencing to? Is that the environment in home or is that within the project directory?

Thank you so much! I feel like I'm missing some chunk from what Python is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm using one in my django project, which is under <project>/src/<project>. So in the top <project> dir I specify the python path as ./src/<project>, so all imports become relative to that.Works nicely, but took me a while and a lot of googling to find that solution!

Comment: I looked at VS Code docs on `python.envFile`. I didn't understand `${workspaceFolder}` and `\\<project>.env` in your answer. I have it set to `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/src/.env"` now. Thanks!

Sorry, but I'm still confused on the PYTHONPATH in `.env` file... For context: I'm not using Django or any frameworks and do not have a special environment anywhere. I also have `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python3"` in settings.json. Should I have this? What is the .env's `PYTHONPATH` supposed to be pointed at in the project root directory?

Comment: Here's some more info on the .env file for vs code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

Comment: Thank you! That .env file makes sense now. Unfortunately, now the program will not even run. Adding `from __init__ import *` back into app.py allows the app to run again, so I do not think my .env and settings.json adjustments are changing things. I'm going to back-up and look at the actual installations of Python. Do you have any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Odd, I'd have to see your file structure, __init__.py file and the files that you're importing in to see what the problem there was though ...

Comment: The file structure and contents are already in the post, and the __init__.py is empty..

Comment: I have my models in seperate files too. In the `__init.py__` file (in the same dir as the model files themselves. So, eg. I have `model1` and `model2` in app_name. `__init.py__` says `from app_name.models.model1 import Model1` and `from app_name.models.model2 import Model2`. I can then use just a standard `from app_name.models import Model1, Model2` wherever I like then.

Comment: Strange, doing it like that runs the program, and even got rid of red squigglies, but the yellow suigglies still exist. Would a problem in my Bash settings cause a linting issue in IDEs and VS Code?

Comment: Not sure what your yellow squigglies are indicating. I do still get red ones under the "from" in the `__init.py__` file. This is simply because I am importing things in that file that are then not referenced in the same file. I don't actually think there's anything to do about that tbh. I do configure vs code to only show things under the "problem" tab for open files though, and since `__init.py__` is basically never open once I've set it up this doesn't bother me.

Comment: Just wondering if the issue is resolved and how? I am getting yellow squiggles line issue same as described in above.


@michjnich: file name might be wrong in your case. Normally it looks like (`__init__.py`) instead of (`__init.py__`) where file extension is changed from .py to .py__ in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You might have created two venv at the root of your directory. For example in  {Python_Projects} root folder you have created test1_venv and test2_venv. You need to delete one of them.

{Python_Projects} root folder you need to create .vscode folder and in which create settings.json. In this json file you need to declare path to your venv python binary. {"python.pythonPath": "test_env/bin/python"}

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that I found. in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
     "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceRoot}/path/to/file"]
}
```

note that you could use wildcards like `*` to add all files in a certain directory like `pkgname/utils/*`.