# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize import despite the script works in virtualenv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

[image]

I'm work using a virtualenv, the script works and doesn't alert "no module error".
Despite VS continue to highlight my import.
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: You probably need to set a source root to a directory where `torch` is located.

Comment: If i execute the script in my virtualenv all works correctly..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up a virtual environment for Python in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106071/how-can-i-set-up-a-virtual-environment-for-python-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333371/how-to-make-vs-code-read-python-imports-without-displaying-yellow-squigglies

Comment: I got that part. That means that source roots are different for VS and wherever you are running your script from.

Comment: i explain the problem clearly, i have folder A that contains another folder for the virtualEnv. Now my settings json contains only this: "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/bundled/stubs/pandas/compat"
    ]. I tried to follow yours suggestion..maybe i don't understand..i need to create a .env inside the virtual env folder and add "python.envFile" in settings.json?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the `PROBLEMS` panel? We want to know what prompts these errors. thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a full screenshot of the VSCode with the `PROBLEMS` panel opened? We want to know which python interpreter you have selected, which prompts the error messages, and If you can provide the terminal panel with the command of executing the python file, that will be great. thanks a lot.